# Directive add event get errror in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Add custom selectbox using directive and change event. below is my snippet.

```
<select class="customSelect" ng-change="changeTheme(theme)">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option custom-select-item ng-repeat="product in theme.productData" value="{{product.product_id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
</select>


app.directive('customSelect', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.initSelectbox = function(element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.selectbox();
            }, 0)                
        }
    }
  };
}]).directive('customSelectItem', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            scope.initSelectbox(element.parent());
        }
    }
  };
}]);
```

When add ng-change="changeTheme(theme)" event in select get error 
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!.
Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because you dnt add ngModel in Select. NgChange is detected by NgModel's value change so when there is no NgModel, no change will be found.

Comment: What should i do for the change event?

Comment: Just include NgModel in select

Comment: so how can i add  custom selectbox without directive?

Comment: <select class="customSelect" ng-model="SelectedProduct" ng-change="changeTheme(theme)">  Is this creat any problem?

Comment: @Jenny Thanks working fine. How is it working?

Comment: The ng-change directive requires a ng-model directive to be present. ng-change checks for changes in ng-model value which is stored when we select or deselect value.

Comment: @Jenny Thank you

Comment: happy to help you.

Comment: @Jenny one last question is that any problem if there r same name multiple ngModal="SelectedProduct"?

Comment: no... ngmodel should be unique for each select.